# Возвращаемое значение в SQL процедуре

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть процедура, которая должна вернуть заголовок, и оценку

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `avg_procedure`(IN first_name VARCHAR(150), OUT title VARCHAR(150),  OUT mark DOUBLE)
BEGIN
        SELECT title, avg(mark) mark FROM student_marks sm 
        JOIN student s ON sm.student_id = s.id
        JOIN  subject sub ON sub.id = sm.subject_id
        WHERE s.first_name = first_name group by title;
END
```

Но почему-то у меня out параметры всегда 0, хотя сам запрос возвращает нужные значения

Comment: *почему-то у меня out параметры всегда 0* Так ты ж в них ничего не присваиваешь...

Comment: В вопроса по SQL, пожалуйста, указывайте СУБД, т.к. синтаксис может сильно отличаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE avg_procedure (IN  first_name VARCHAR(150), 
                                OUT title VARCHAR(150),  
                                OUT mark DOUBLE)
SELECT title, avg(mark)
INTO title, mark   -- Отправить результаты в OUT-переменные
FROM student_marks sm 
JOIN student s ON sm.student_id = s.id
JOIN  subject sub ON sub.id = sm.subject_id
WHERE s.first_name = first_name 
GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: А если у меня select будет возвращать несколько строк

Comment: Значит, будете выкручиваться в рамках имеющихся средств. Вариант 1 - LIMIT 1. Вариант 2 - темптаблица. Вариант 3 - сериализация (да хоть в JSON). Вариант 4 - вывод в stdout, и пусть клиент разгребает. И т.д...